# How to set a conditional breakpoint in Rust in GDB for string equality

Tags: rust, gdb, conditional-breakpoint

Seems like a basic question, but I couldn't find anything.

How do I set a conditional breakpoint in Rust in GDB, for string equality?

I have the function:

```rust
fn find_max_subst(subst_word: &String, other_word: &String) -> u64 {
```

I would like to break on `*subst_word == "BROAD" && *other_word == "BOARD"`, but setting this breakpoint on the first line of the function does not work, it just breaks regardless of the values.

Doing the following in GDB doesn't work either:

```
(gdb) p *subst_word == "CREATION"
Structure has no component named operator==.
```